# How did software copyright work in the US before 1978?

Tags: copyright, public-domain

Prior to the Copyright Act of 1976 (which, confusingly, only went into effect in 1978) the copyright rules were different. One of the things that was introduced was that after the beginning of 1978, software could be explicitly copyrighted.

So, what about software which was published before 1978? I've seen a variety of opinions.

- that it can't be copyrighted at all.
- that the *representation* of the software can be copyrighted. For example, a magnetic tape containing the program. But the program itself can't be.
- that the *source code*, being a literary work, can be copyrighted, but the object code which can't be read by humans can't be.
- that it works the same way as it does today (although with an expiry date of publish + 28 + 28 years).

The reason why this is interesting is that it may or may not make pre-1978 software public domain in certain circumstances, even if it was published with a copyright notice.

Does anyone actually know about any of this? Finding information on pre-1978 copyright is like pulling hen's teeth.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question does not relate to Open Source Software (even though the OP tries to create a connection). It relates to copyright law and should be answered by Law SE or a historian. Furthermore, due to the fast developments in IT, it is unlikely that pre-1978 software has any impact on current OSS projects.

Comment: I disagree on both counts. Making software available in the public domain absolutely relates to open source. And there's plenty of pre-1978 software around, a lot of which is vanishing without trace due to unclear rights issues, and some of it's still being used today: I have one work from 1976 in mind which is widely used in the retrocomputing community, and I'm trying to find out if this is legal or not.

Comment: Then you might want to ask on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ , where I notice you're active.

Comment: Can a mod move this question, or should I repost (I ask because SO frequently gets shirty about reposts)?

Comment: I did, but they've thrown it back.  At the moment, it's not at all clear to me where it might go.

Comment: @MadHatter, I was one of the voters that "threw it back" though my intent was much less "violent" than that :-) I suspect that, given it's at its core a legal question, it may be better off over at https://law.stackexchange.com. There are already quite a few questions with the `software` and `copyright` tags, including possibly two in the following query that may cause this one closed as a dupe: https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=software+copyright+1978